# Getting "Parameter count mismatch" for no reason

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface TestInterface 
{    
     List<string> TestMethod(List<string> ids);

     List<string> TestMethod(List<string> ids, bool testBool);    
}
```

This interface is implemented by a class called `TestClass`, but this isn't important.

Now, I have a unit test which does the following:

```
List<string> testReturnData = GetSomeTestReturnData(); //Not important

Mock<TestInterface> mockedInterface = new Mock<TestInterface>();

mockedInterface.Setup(d => d.TestMethod(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), true).Returns(testReturnData);
```

Then eventually I run the unit test, which in turn runs some actual code where the above `mockedInterface` is used:

```
List<string> someValidInput = GetSomeValidInput(); //Not important
//  Line causing the exception. testInterfaceInstance is actually the mocked interface 
//  instance, passed in as a reference
List<string> returnData = testInterfaceInstance.TestMethod(someValidInput, true);
```

When the above line is executed, the following exception is immediately thrown:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

Can someone explain why is this happening ? I'm providing valid number of inputs. The expected behavior is that calling the above should return `testReturnData` that was mentioned earlier.

In the mocked interface setup, even if I replace `true` with `It.IsAny<Boolean>()`, it still doesn't solve the issue.

EDIT:

Actually I figured out the issue. In the mock setup, there was a callback that was using just one input parameter, which was confusing the compiler. I didn't think it was important, so I left it out :) ... More detail: The actual call was this:

```
mockedInterface.Setup(d => d.TestMethod(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), true).Returns(testReturnData)
.Callback<IEnumerable<string>>(u =>
                {
                    u.ToList();
                });
```

I simply had to change the `Callback` to this:

```
mockedInterface.Setup(d => d.TestMethod(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<string>>(), true).Returns(testReturnData)
.Callback<IEnumerable<string>, Boolean>((u, v) =>
                {
                    u.ToList();
                });
```

And then the test was running fine. :)

Comment: Have you tried using `It.IsAny<List<string>>` so that the type you're passing in matches the real parameter type? (If you could provide a [mcve] so that we could easily reproduce this, that would really help.)

Comment: Have you tried renaming the second method of your `interface`? Maybe `Moq` finds the wrong method at runtime?

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I figured out the problem. I mentioned it in my code above as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code example is missing some stuff. Are you getting the `.Object` from your mock?

Based on your code I could produce this, and this doesn't throw:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public interface TestInterface
    {
        List<string> TestMethod(List<string> ids);

        List<string> TestMethod(List<string> ids, bool testBool);
    }


    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Foo()
        {
            List<string> testReturnData = new List<string>();
            Mock<TestInterface> mockedInterface = new Mock<TestInterface>();
            mockedInterface
                .Setup(d => d.TestMethod(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), true)).Returns(testReturnData);

            List<string> someValidInput = new List<string>();
            var testInterfaceInstance = mockedInterface.Object;
            List<string> returnData = testInterfaceInstance.TestMethod(someValidInput, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is using `xUnit` as a test runner.